# R.matlab - Cannot start server

Tags: r, matlab

I'm trying to use the `R.matlab` package but frankly I'm not able to start the Matlab server.

I'm on OS X 10.11.5 and use Matlab R2015b.

Within R I get

```
> Matlab()
[1] "Matlab: The MATLAB host is 'localhost' and communication goes via port 9999. Objects are passed via the local file system (remote=FALSE). The connection to the MATLAB server is closed (not opened)."
> Matlab$startServer()
[1] 0
sh: matlab: command not found
```

But within a terminal I can indeed launch Matlab with the `matlab` command.

Also within a Terminal

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r MatlabServer
```

results in

```
Undefined function or variable 'MatlabServer'.
>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it to run matlab from terminal. You just to go to your user profile `~/usr/your_nickame` and edit file **.bash_profile** in any editor (and save!) and add

```
alias matlab=“/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab”
```

That way terminal knows what you mean by matlab and where to find it and execute it. And it will make the alias permanent. That is option if you are starting the server from *terminal*

If you want to start it from R directly, I managed to make it work by setting what *matlab* command runs:

```
options(matlab="/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab")
```

Then the usual works:

```
     require(R.matlab)
      Matlab$startServer()
      matlab <- Matlab()
      isOpen <- open(matlab)
   < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2015 The MathWorks, Inc.
                   R2015a (8.5.0.197613) 64-bit (maci64)
                             February 12, 2015


To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

Running MatlabServer v3.5.9-9000
MATLAB v7.x or higher detected.
Saving with option -V6.
Added InputStreamByteWrapper to dynamic Java CLASSPATH.
----------------------
MATLAB server started!
----------------------
MATLAB working directory: /Users/air/Desktop/Dissertation/myPack/finalPack
Trying to open server socket (port 9999)...Error using MatlabServer (line 130)
Java exception occurred:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at
        java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128) 
>> 
>
```

Comment: even after such a long time. many thanks. greatly appreciated.